PVC in lost state and PV in pending state
So, I have an EKS cluster running EFS CSI controller as an addon. I have created an EFS using AWS console and created a storage class using the EFS. Further, whenever I try to create a PVC using the storage class I can see a PV is created but remains in pending state. The PVC itself remains in lost state. The kubectl describe command for pvc shows a
ClaimLost  warning with Bound claim has lost reference to PersistentVolume. Data on the volume is lost!

However PV describe commands returns just the state as pending. The EFS CSI controller does not have any error messages and states that the EFS access point has been created and which can be viewed in AWS console. Can anyone help in understanding as to how to debug this ?
